# Making a gulpfile: getting an error when call gulp.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm working through the book *Getting Started With Gulp* (which was published in January 2015) but I realize that because development with Gulp is moving quite fast it may be slightly out of date already.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
// Modules & Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var myth = require('gulp-myth');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // newly added
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint'); // newly added
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
// let's add two node.js modules:
var connect = require('connect');
// var serve = require('serve-static');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// Tasks
// styles task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
    // now we add our pipes:
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(myth())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// images task
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/*')
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

// browsersync Task:
gulp.task('browsersync', function(cb) {
    return browsersync({
      server: {
        baseDir:'./'
      }
    }, cb);
});

// browserify Task:
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('./app/js/app.js')
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// watch task:
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css',
   gulp.series('styles', browsersync.reload));
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js',
   gulp.series('scripts', browsersync.reload));
  gulp.watch('app/img/*',
   gulp.series('images', browsersync.reload));
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'images', 'browsersync', 'browserify', 'watch']);
```

EDIT:  After changing the final `gulp.task` line, it runs but I still get the following error:

```
[13:51:21] Starting 'watch'...
[13:51:21] 'watch' errored after 146 μs
[13:51:21] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Volumes/BigMan/Code/javascript/gulp-book/gulpfile.js:79:9)
    at module.exports (/Volumes/BigMan/Code/javascript/gulp-book/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Volumes/BigMan/Code/javascript/gulp-book/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Volumes/BigMan/Code/javascript/gulp-book/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Volumes/BigMan/Code/javascript/gulp-book/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: What version of gulp?

Comment: The version is 3.8.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where the gulp.parallel or gulp.series is coming from but you should be able to accomplish the same thing by changing your code to this:

```
// watch task:
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', ['styles', browsersync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', ['scripts', browsersync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('app/img/*', ['images', browsersync.reload]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'images', 'browsersync', 'browserify', 'watch']);
```

As far as I can tell .series and .parallel don't exist. Once I made those updates it works.

If you need to run tasks in series, I have had good luck with this module: https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence. You would change your watch task to this:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

// watch task:
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', runSequence('styles', browsersync.reload));
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', runSequence('scripts', browsersync.reload));
  gulp.watch('app/img/*', runSequence('images', browsersync.reload));
});
```

Comment: I changed my code and while gulp runs, it is now giving me the error that is in my updated question.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to Gulp (node.js in general) and I really need to spend some time on streams

Comment: .series and .parellel are in Gulp version 4. These will render run-sequence obsolete.

Comment: It's a year and a half later and there's still no sign of Gulp 4 on npm.

Answer (score 22):

### I'm reading the same book and found it extrange that it doesn't work. I noticed all you had to do was to update Gulp to 4.0

### Why isn't it working

In order to accomplish the parallel and series feature from Gulp, you must install Gulp 4.0

### How to install

#### Global installation

```
npm uninstall gulp -g
npm install gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0 -g
```

or

```
yarn global add gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0
```

#### From within your project

```
npm uninstall gulp
npm install gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0 --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0
```

I also found a bunch of tutorials talking about the new features from Gulp 4.0

I'm assuming this is because the book was written with the upcoming features in mind. I think that sometimes it cannot be assumed that the project will move as fast. What I still don't understand is the difference between `gulp.parallel` and just passing an array.

http://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

One more thing:

In gulp4 you must specify parallel/series for the watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', gulp.parallel('styles'));
    gulp.watch('app/jss/*.js', gulp.parallel('scripts'));
    gulp.watch('app/img/*', gulp.parallel('images'));
})
```

Comment: Interesting.  Here is the [migration guide](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/861) for version 3.x to 4.0 where you can read up more on the usage of `parallel`.

Comment: gulp-cli does not have 4.0 version, gulp does. We need upgrade only gulp. Rest of the comment is accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any reference of gulp-cli in the comments or the request except for the npm install for gulpjs. Your comment can be confusing for other people trying to figure this out. For some reason at the time of writing this  gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0 helped install the right version.